# PIP upgrade package not working correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, python-requests, virtualenv

I have a server with python 2.7.3 and PIP 1.1. I can't upgrade them right now.

I was trying them to upgrade Requests package from 2.0.0 to 2.4.0. So I simply ran the following command, inside the virtualenv I have:

```
pip install --upgrade -i https://pypi.python.org/simple/ requests==2.4.0
```

It returned this:

Downloading/unpacking requests==2.4.0
  Running setup.py egg_info for package requests

```
Installing collected packages: requests
  Found existing installation: requests 2.0.0
    Uninstalling requests:
      Successfully uninstalled requests
  Running setup.py install for requests

  Could not find .egg-info directory in install record for requests==2.4.0
Successfully installed requests
Cleaning up...
```

But after I check Python, inside the virtual env of course, it still returns version 2.0.0. Also if I check the path to the lib inside the virtual env it still have version 2.0.0 installed and not 2.4.0.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

> [EDIT] - - - - - - -

I was able to fix it. The thing is, apparently it's a known issue of PIP 1.1 that it doesn't delete the already installed package from build folder, and then reuses it as it was the new version you are trying to install. So what I did was to delete the requests package inside build and re-run the command to upgrade.

Comment: What do you mean "pip 1.1"?

Comment: But you can upgrade `pip` inside a virtual environment?

Comment: @phd I meant pip --version
pip 1.1 from /var/www/htdocs/my_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)

Comment: @hoefling Unfortunately I can't upgrade. And the strange thing is that for installing new packages it work nicely. Just for upgrading that it doesnt.

Comment: [pip 1.1](https://pypi.org/project/pip/1.1/), 2012 year? python 2.7.3? Definitely time to upgrade.

Comment: Even if you can't upgrade the system pip, you still can upgrade the packages inside the venv, including pip. `source venvname && pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: I’m really afraid of upgrading pip and breaking such legacy system. Do you recommend it either way? @phd Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @hoefling I haven’t tried but as it’s not being able to upgrade requests, why it would update/upgrade pip?  Perhaps if I uninstall and reinstall Requests it would work? Thing is, it’s a server running nginx + uwsgi and python including Requests. Thanks!